# Imported target "GLEW::GLEW" includes non-existent path (a MacOSX SDK I don't have)

Tags: macos, opengl, cmake

I have a CMake project that uses glew. Yesterday it was working without errors.
I did't make any change to the cmakelists and now I'm getting this:

```
[cmake]   Imported target "GLEW::GLEW" includes non-existent path"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework"
[cmake]   in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.
```

This is my cmakelists file:

```
    include_directories(/opt/homebrew/include)
    include_directories(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/include)
    set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} Wno-deprecated")
    find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories(${GLUT_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    add_definitions(${GLUT_DEFINITIONS})
    find_package(GLEW 2.0 REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories(${GLEW_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    add_definitions(${GLEW_DEFINITIONS})

    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "-F${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/System/Library/Frameworks" "-framework GLUT")
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "-F${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/System/Library/Frameworks" "-framework OpenGL")
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} GLEW::GLEW)
```

I didn't find this exact problem anywhere. Can you point me in the right direction?

I tried setting MAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to what I think are the only possible paths `set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk")` and `set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk")` but I always get the same error.

In the `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/` I have these two sdk's: MacOSX13.3.sdk and MacOSX13.sdk so it makes sense it's not finding 13.1.
I don't understand where it's getting the 13.1 from.
I don't know if It's related but I was opening a file with xcode and I was asked to install even though it was already installed.

Comment: Note: shouldn't your `Wno-deprecated` be `-Wno-deprecated`?

Comment: "_and I was asked to install even though it was already installed_" asked to install what exactly?

Comment: did you ever have MacOSX13.1.sdk on this machine at any point in time? Did you install you did recently do an upgrade? What if you re-configure the project with a fresh CMake variable cache? (run cmake's command to generate the buildsystem with the [`--fresh`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-fresh) flag)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'm not sure, it's working with Wno-deprecated for some reason.
--"and I was asked to install even though it was already installed" asked to install what exactly? 
I can't recall exactly. 
Deleting the build folder solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some kind of stale data in your CMake variable cache (the CMakeCache.txt file in your build folder). Perhaps you previously had MacOSX13.1.sdk, and your recent action caused an update to MacOSX1331.sdk. You can delete the build folder and reconfigure to repopulate the cache with fresh info, or you can run the configure command with the [`--fresh`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-fresh) flag.